# Rendering multiple items in html

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to render both form and a list of items.  The goal is to output a list of accounts below the form.

I have this in my view:

```
return render(request, 'add_user_accounts.html', 
    {'form': form}, 
    {'accounts': account},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception Value: render() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context_instance'
```

My html:

```
{% block content %}

{% load staticfiles %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery.js' %}"></script>
{% include 'autocomplete_light/static.html' %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Add account" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>


{% for account in accounts %}
    <li>{{ account }}</li>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `render()` does *not need* the context_instance parameter at all, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

`return render(request, 'add_user_accounts.html', 
    {'form': form, 
    'accounts': account})`

You have to remove this; `,context_instance=RequestContext(request)`

Answer (score 1):

You must using one dict for passing parameters to render functions.

```
return render(request, 'add_user_accounts.html', 
    {'form': form,
    'accounts': account},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You got this error because you pass firstly form dict as a context parameter than accounts dicts as context_instance parameter and than try to pass context_instance parameter again. Also you can simple remove context_instance parameter. From docs:

> The context_instance argument is deprecated. Simply use context.

Full docs: 
[render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)